# Spring Data Solr with Dynamic Field not working

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I am trying to index a document with dynamic fields and have it defined:

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "collection1")
public class SolrProduct {

    @Field
    String id;

    @Field
    String name;

    @Field("mappedField_*")
    Map<String, List<String>> mappedFieldValues;
}
```

And the following repo:

```
public interface SolrProductRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<SolrProduct, String> { }
```

My solr schema is as follows:

```
<field name="name" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="mappedField_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I am trying to save a new document where the value of the mappedFieldValues Map is:

> {thermometer=[yes], camera=[yes], vibration=[Motion], brand=[Philips]}

Yet, I get the following exception:

> ```
> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:
> ```
>
> ERROR: [doc=5530cbd78b15a5f18dfe3d28] unknown field 'thermometer'
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:495)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:199)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:118)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:116)
>         at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate$4.doInSolr(SolrTemplate.java:178)
>         at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate$4.doInSolr(SolrTemplate.java:175)
>         at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:132)
>         at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:175)
>         at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:169)
>         at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository.save(SimpleSolrRepository.java:149)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:401)
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>         at $Proxy60.save(Unknown Source)
>         at com.example.Indexer.indexAll(Indexer.java:29)

So it seems to me that the spring-data-solr does not properly call solr with the dynamic fields name (instead of mappedField_thermometer it simply calls thermometer).

Any ideas?

Comment: please have a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307653/how-to-serialize-deserialize-a-map-with-solr-lucene/29340019#29340019

Answer (score 1):

Spring data solr supports dynamic field mapping
for example in my project i have configured any field names to Object type

```
@org.springframework.data.solr.core.mapping.Dynamic
@org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field("*")
private ListOrderedMap<String, Object> fieldValueMap;
```

as you can see any field values maps to this map.
but in your project in solr configuration you have said just map fields that starting with "mappedField_*" so if you change your field names to mappedField_yourField it will work correctly